# Anyway to return JSON from form.submit()

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Morning,

I am submitting a form from jquery like:

```
$('#form').submit();
```

which successfully submits the form onto the server. However, I would like to return JSON from the post so I can dynamically update a modal without any redirection.

Though I could change my submit into a AJAX request. (so the return contents from the method will enter the success callback in the AJAX code) I already have the controller method accept my ViewModel object from the post so I can do easy validation on the server e.g.

```
If ModelState.IsValid Then
```

also I have the objects accessible to me (other posts suggest to serialize the data but with 20+ properties being sent, this will take a lot of effort on the server)

Is there anyway I can keep this same logic and return JSON? or will a re-write be required?

Thanks

Comment: To serialize your form, its one line of code - `$(form).serialize()` (and there is no difference on the server)

Comment: do you want to refresh the page after the submit??

Comment: I dont want to refresh after submit, I just to return JSON after the submit. so no redirection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the form data from the form and make an AJAX call.

```
$('#form').submit(function(){
   $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(json) {
     alert(json);
   }, 'json');
   return false; // important to have this
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Return json_encode($data) from your PHP file